# Windows CLI alternative to robocopy and xcopy

Tags: windows, backup, sync, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am looking for windows console-based tools similar to xcopy or robocopy. I have to send file into writable but not readable net share directory (unix privileges 333). Both tools are great however I need something with resume again after a pause or interruption.

Firstly I was using robocopy with switch /Z, however finally I have to use net share without read privileges - tool cannot list directory only can save or add content into files.

I have to send 10-30GB archives over network that's way resume mode is necessary.

It would be nice if I could limit upload.

Comment: Have you tried RichCopy?

Answer (score 1):

Try some "rsync" Windows port (there are many, cwRsync is probably the best).